# modifying html list with PHP and SimpleDOM or SimpleXML

Tags: php, html-parsing, simplexml, simpledom

i have a HTML piece with this structure:

```
<li class="level1 item3 parent">
    <a href="mainlink.html" class="level1 item3 parent">
        <span>
            <span class="title">Main title</span>
            <span class="sub">Subtitle</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level2">
        <li class="level2 item1 first">
            <a href="alink.html" class="level2 item1 first"><span>Title 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 item2">
            <a href="alink.html" class="level2 item2"><span>Title 2</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 item3">
            <a href="alink.html" class="level2 item3"><span>Title 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 item4 last">
            <a href="alink.html" class="level2 item4 last"><span>Title 4</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to change it into this:

```
<li class="level1 item3 parent">
    <a href="mainlink.html" class="level1 item3 parent">
        <span>
            <span class="title">Main title</span>
            <span class="sub">Subtitle</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level2">
        <li class="level2 item1 first">
            <a href="mainlink.html" class="level2 item1 first"><span>Main title</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 item1">
            <a href="alink.html" class="level2 item2"><span>Title 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 item2">
            <a href="alink.html" class="level2 item3"><span>Title 2</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 item3">
            <a href="alink.html" class="level2 item4"><span>Title 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 item4 last">
            <a href="alink.html" class="level2 item5 last"><span>Title 4</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The main idea is to add a new item at the beginning of the ul inside the main li element, cloning part of the a tag heading that li element. I don't know how to use SimpleXML or SimpleDOM http://code.google.com/p/simpledom/ to acomplish this task... any ideas?

regards,

Comment: Dom is quite simple and PHP already have DOM lib [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.dom.php) why you want to import another one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version :

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$li = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li')->item(0)->cloneNode(true);

foreach($li->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $ul) {
    $ul->parentNode->removeChild($ul);
}

$span = $li->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0);
$span->nodeValue = $li->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(1)->nodeValue;
foreach($span->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    $a->setAttribute('class', 'level2 item1 first');
}

$ul = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0);

$nodes = $ul->getElementsByTagName('a');
$node = $ul->childNodes->item(0);

$i = 2;
foreach($nodes as $n) {
    $n->setAttribute('class', 'level2 item' . $i);
    $i++;
}

$ul->insertBefore($li, $node);

$nodes->item(1)->parentNode->setAttribute('class', 'level2 item1');

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

http://codepad.org/pIwwK1Z5

Comment: It looks fine... but there is a little problem already, when creating the new li at top, you are using hardcoded values, and it must use values from the a tag inside the main li element. 'mainlink.html' and 'Main title' are only example values... it should take any other values being used and copy them into the new created element...

Comment: Try this new one ! I may have done some mistakes. Fast codding !

Comment: Amazing! Now i need to change it a bit, because there is many blocks like the one in my post. So the main structure is: <ul class="menu">[block1] [block2] ... [block n]</ul> each code [block] has the li class as "level1 item1", "level1 item2" "level1 item3"... etc